# How To Create Multiple Loopback Cards Using Alsa?

Tags: 20.04, sound, alsa

I Have A Requirement Where I Need To Create Multiple Loopback Devices In ALSA. Using The Command Below I Am Only Able To Create One Pair Of Cards:

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop
```

How Can I Create Many Of These Cards?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`sudo modprobe snd-aloop`
```

just loads the kernel module (driver).What you want to do is give it parameters. For example:

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop index=0 id=loop0
sudo modprobe snd-aloop index=1 id=loop1
```

To verify the available devices:

```
 cat /proc/asound/cards
```

you can configure /etc/modprobe.d/snd-aloop.conf
to set these devices on boot like this:

```
echo "options snd-aloop index=0 id=loop0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/snd-aloop.conf
echo "options snd-aloop index=1 id=loop1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/snd-aloop.conf
```

This will add the parameters index and id to the snd-aloop module configuration, ensuring that the loopback devices are created with the specified IDs during system boot.
Use the `alsamixer` command to configure each loopback device if needed. Adjust the volume levels and other settings using the arrow keys and the "M" key to mute/unmute.